# How to create a progress chart (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have searched this site to solve my problem, but could not find it.

I am creating a competition league table for a local handball league. I have created
two tables that look like this:

teams: id int primary key auto_increment,tname varchar 50

games: idmatch int primary key auto_increment, matchday tinyint, date datetime, hteam int, ateam int, hscore tinyint,ascore tinyint

Here is my query:

```
SELECT @rowno:= @rowno+1 as position, total.*
from (SELECT matchday,tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,
Sum(L) AS L, SUM(F) AS F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(Pts) AS Pts 
FROM( SELECT
matchday,hteam Team, 1 P,
IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W,
IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D,
IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L,
hscore F,
ascore A,
CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
FROM games
UNION ALL
SELECT
matchday,ateam, 1,
IF(hscore < ascore,1,0),
IF(hscore = ascore,1,0),
IF(hscore > ascore,1,0),
ascore,
hscore,
CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM games) AS tot
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id
CROSS JOIN   (SELECT @rowno := 0) r
WHERE matchday <= 1
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY  SUM(Pts) DESC, SUM(F) DESC)total
ORDER BY Pts DESC, F DESC
```

With the help from Gordon the rank order is working, but now I can´t figure out how to create a progress chart from this query and create something like [this](http://shrani.najdi.si/?J/Zj/4d7IGbM2/progressbar.jpg). To make it more clear what I want to achieve is that for example Team A is first after matchday one and third after matchday two and forth after matchday three. It it gives me values for the chart so in my example the values should be 1,3 and 4. Here is my query example [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a036d/38/0).

Hopefully someone could help me find a solution.

Comment: why it should be in third place while you order by position ?? and team D have position 4 then its right .

Comment: The team D should be in third place because they have 7 points and team C only 6 points.

Comment: look my answer duude if you want it to be in third place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `order by` to `order by sum(pts) desc`:

```
SELECT @rowno:= @rowno+1 as position, tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,
       Sum(L) AS L, SUM(F) AS F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(Pts) AS Pts 
FROM (SELECT hteam Team, 1 P, IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W,
             IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D, IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L,
             hscore F, ascore A,
             CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
      FROM games
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ateam, 1, IF(hscore < ascore,1,0),
             IF(hscore = ascore,1,0), IF(hscore > ascore,1,0),
             ascore, hscore,
             CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      FROM games
     ) AS tot JOIN
     teams t ON tot.Team=t.id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rowno := 0) row
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC ;
```

The variable calculation occurs *after* the ordering.  If you want your original order, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
order by position ASC, Pts DESC;
```

EDIT:

Your comment is very strange, but reproducible.  Using a subquery fixes the problem:

```
select @rowno:= @rowno+1 as position, t.*
from (SELECT tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,
             Sum(L) AS L, SUM(F) AS F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(Pts) AS Pts 
      FROM (SELECT hteam Team, 1 P, IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W,
                   IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D, IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L,
                   hscore F, ascore A,
                   CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
            FROM games
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ateam, 1, IF(hscore < ascore,1,0),
                   IF(hscore = ascore,1,0), IF(hscore > ascore,1,0),
                   ascore, hscore,
                   CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM games
           ) AS tot JOIN
           teams t ON tot.Team=t.id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rowno := 0) row
      GROUP BY Team
     ) t
  ORDER BY Pts DESC ;
```

Comment: That is not the solution because now the order is 1,2,4,3 and it should be 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Headpetrol . . . That is very strange behavior.  The variable assignment should be happening *after* the `order by`.  In any case, using a subquery assigns the correct rank.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the help!

Answer (score 0):

then just change your order by to this

```
    ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC;
```